# Null Pointer Exception - Java Program for GPA HH

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

This is for homework.  I'm 90% of the way through this but an NPE is causing my program to fail every time.  I've tried several methods and read the instructions which are very detailed in how he wants the program structured and I still can't figure out why it's giving this exception even when data is passed.  I originally assumed it was because data was not being passed on the initial test.

First .java file where the program is run from:

```
class TestGPA
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    if (args.length == 0)
    {
        System.out.println("Please supply grades to find GPA");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    GPA gpa = new GPA(args);
    else
    {
        GPA gpa = new GPA(args);
        gpa.displayResult();
    }
  }
}
```

Second .java file where a lot of the methods are located:

```
class GPA
{
String[] courseIdGrades;
String[] courseIds;
char[] grades;
double gpa;
String errorMsg;

GPA(String[] courseIdGrades)
{
    String[] courseIds = new String[courseIdGrades.length];
    char[] grades = new char[courseIdGrades.length];
    processData();
}

void parseInput()
{
    int i = 0;
    while( i < courseIdGrades.length )
    {
        GPAUtil.validateCourseIdGrade(courseIdGrades[i]);
        if(errorMsg != "NO_ERROR")
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            courseIds[i] = courseIdGrades[i].substring(0,5).toUpperCase();
            grades[i] = Character.toUpperCase(courseIdGrades[i].charAt(5));
            i++;    
        }
    }
}

double computeGPA()
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++)
    {
        sum += GPAUtil.gradePoints(grades[i]);
    }
    double gpa = (double) sum / grades.length;
    return gpa;
}

void processData()
{
    parseInput();
    if(errorMsg == "NO_ERROR")
    {
        computeGPA();
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Input error - details are: " + errorMsg);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

void displayResult()
{
    System.out.println("--------------------");
    System.out.println(" Course ID Grade" );
    System.out.println("--------------------");
    for (int i = 0; i < courseIds.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(" " + courseIds[i] + " " + grades[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("--------------------");
    System.out.println(" GPA = " + gpa);
    System.out.println("--------------------");
}
}
```

Third .java that is a utility class:

```
public class GPAUtil
{

public static String[] validDepts = {"CS","EE","ME"};

public static String validateCourseIdGrade(String courseIdGrade)
{
    String errorMsg = "NO_ERROR";

    if (courseIdGrade.length() != 6)
    {
        errorMsg = "Course ID/Grade string invalid, must be 6 char.";
    }

    else
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            if(courseIdGrade.substring(0,2).equalsIgnoreCase(validDepts[i]))
            {
                errorMsg = "NO_ERROR";
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                errorMsg = "Dept ID invalid, must be one of: CS, EE, ME";
            }

        }

    }

    return errorMsg;

}


static int gradePoints(char grade)
{
    int points = 0;
    switch(grade)
    {
        case 'A':
            points = 4;
            break;
        case 'B':
            points = 3;
            break;
        case 'C':
            points = 2;
            break;
        case 'D':
            points = 1;
            break;
        default:
            points = 0;
            break;
    }
    return points;
}

}
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at GPA.parseInput(GPA.java:19)
at GPA.processData(GPA.java:48)
at GPA.<init>(GPA.java:13)
at TestGPA.main(TestGPA.java:5)
```

#### Input

According to the error message the problem occurs in the GPA class with this line: `while( i < courseIdGrades.length )` which lead me to believe that by not passing an argument it was resolving to null and thus had no length so I added a check for null.  However, when I pass an argument I still receive the same set of errors.  I'm not asking for the answer, but a nudge in the right direction would be very helpful.

#### What I've tried

I've tried restructuring the code to read `while(i < courseIdGrades[i].length())` to no avail and also hardcoded an argument and started passing that but still received the same treatment.  What should be happening is if invalid arguments are passed it should display: `Input error - details are:  + errorMsg` given by the `errorMsg` variable located in `GPAUtil`.

Comment: So courseIdGrades is null, as it's the only reference in that line. Why is is null? Figure that out and you'll have it fixed.

Comment: Thanks bmargulies. I figured the bulk of it out, I've been fiddling with this for a few hours, took a 10 minute coffee break and came back to it and saw I didn't use the "this.variable = variable"  It's not working yet but the NPE is gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're never initializing `courseIdGrades`. You are only initializing `courseIds` and `grades` in your `GPA` constructor. This is why you are getting an exception when referencing the object.

Comment: Thanks, I initialized them with the "this." and that got rid of the NPE.  Now if I could just figure out whey a method isn't returning it's value this would be done!